# php upload file multiple

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple upload textbox that I generate based on questions in my database. Right now my problem is that at the input, I have written `<input type="file" name="file[<?php echo $id;?>]"/>`, and when i want to save it, I write the program as `$_FILES['file']['name'][$start];` where `$start` is a number I declared to match the question number. For example, if the `file[123]` is in the textbox, the post field when saving the information is also `$_FILES['file']['name'][123]`.

But when I try to find if the textbox `file[123]` sent something like `$_FILES['file']['name'][$start]<>""`, it posts nothing.

This is the code when saving the information:

```
    <input multiple name="file[<?php echo id;?>]" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100"> 

    if ($_FILES['file']['name'][$start]<>""){
        $fname=$_FILES['file']['name'][$start];
         $tandatangan=$fname;
         mysql_query("UPDATE answer SET document='$tandatangan' WHERE user_id='$id_user' and id_question='$id_soalan' ");
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../files/$tandatangan");
        }
```

Comment: This is in dire need of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Using `mysql_query` in new applications is also a bad idea as it's being phased out and will be removed entirely in future versions of PHP.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your reply.. please dont look at the mysql_query escaping thing yet.. i just need the name of file that i send form the textbox name=file[123].. thanks again..